# Не могу разбить блок <div> на две равных части для моего контента

Tags: html, css

Верстаю блок в котором нужно 2 блока. Первый для полей регистрации, второй для картинки. Использую классы бутсрапа и прописываю в каждом блоке col-md-6 и тот же результат если пропишу стиль width:50% в каждом. Как не крути даже если уменьшаю колонки до col-md-4 то два блока идут друг под другом. Когда в консоле нахожу эти элементы то они вроде ка бы поделены поровну. Блок действительно разделен на 2 равные части, но во второй не могу ничего поместить. Всеравно идет под первым блоком. Всюду марджины и падинги на ноль поставил. Вот код

```
  <div class="col-md-12" style="height:500px;">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">
            <h3>
                Реєстрація на навчання
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div  style="margin:0px; width:50%; padding:0px;">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <div>
                        <span style="font-size:22px;">Ім'я</span>
                        <br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <span style="font-size:22px;">Прізвище</span>
                        <br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Surname)
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <span style="font-size:22px;">Email</span>
                        <br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "email" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="col-md-5" style="padding:0px;">
                        <img src="/Account/GetImage" />
                        @Html.TextBox("CaptchaCode", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <input id="Submit1" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Зареєструватися" />
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:50%">
            тут будет картинка
        </div>
    </div>
```

В данном коде использую width:50% но с col-md-6 одинаковый результат. 
Что не так с версткой и какие может нужны стили CSS

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых: зачем вы после дивов ставите br??? По ощущениям вы осваиваете бутстрап на автодополнении и не полном. Вот вам ссылка счастья https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ в этом примере можете узнать про прекрасную штуку row. Зачем вы вкладываете тонну дивов друг в друга и указываете класс col-md-12??? В вашем коде нужно выкинуть процентов 60-70 всего объёма. Тут вопрос нужен не в том, почему у вас не так работает, а в том, что вы основы даже не осилили и не понимаете для чего нужны базовые элементы. Я бы даже посоветовал пройти курсы

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-html

и

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-css

а затем (bootstrap тут)

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/make-a-website

Comment: 1. Ставлю br на скорую руку что б видеть результат. Позже все переношу в CSS. Во вторых там нормальное количество блоков ровно для того что б сверстать 2 блока в одном. Формы тоже сегодня много кто верстает блоками , а не таблицами и скажу уверенно что так удобнее. В третьих курсы тут ни к чему. В четвертых не флудите в ответах. Спасибо. И да мне чисто интересно, какой блок вы тут лишний увидели? 1. Главный блок, в нем: два еще блока(которые я не могу разделить) и каждом блоке форма в своем блоке. Каждая строчка отдельно. Вы наверно много divov не видели раз вас это удивило. Проблему уже решил